# How to fix background Opacity css

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is possible to  implement the opacity only to the background and not to the text ?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zbsd/

```
.box
{
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
color: #fff;
height: auto;
width: 232px;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: nope. you will need to create 2 layers, one for background with opacity, and one for the text without opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are - http://jsfiddle.net/4Zbsd/7/

On the background property use rgba color - "background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);"

```
 .box
    {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    width: 232px;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. add another element with `width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bsckgorund: #fff; opacity: .7`
2. shorter, not for older browsers, use RGBA background, so: `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use RGBA on the background. Something like this:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```